# Adding another div dynamically pushes all scrolls of previous divs up

Tags: jquery, html, scrollbar

My html looks like this:

```
<div id="main">
  <div style="height:200px; width:100px; overflow:scroll; display:inline-block;">
    hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="clickme" />
```

and my jquery looks like this:

```
$('#clickme').on('click', function()
{ 
    $('#main').html($('#main').html() + '<div style="height:200px; width:100px; overflow:scroll; display:inline-block;"> hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/></div>');  
});
```

This is a live example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egcux).

When I scroll down the first div and click submit, it should add another div to the right of it but NOT scroll the first div up. It took me ages to realize what the problem was, so I thought I would share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple though. I was adding the controls into html the wrong way. I should have done it using `insertAfter` function in jquery like this:

```
$('#clickme').on('click', function()
{
    $('<div style="height:200px; width:100px; overflow:scroll; display:inline-block;">   hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  hi<br/>  </div>')
    .insertAfter($('#main').children().last());  
});
```

as shown in this [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lrqyz).